# Find volume of an object $y=1-x^2$ $\ldots$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

The $X$ and $Y$ axis, and curve $y=1-x^2$ define an area $\mathbf{A}$ from the first quarter of an $XY$ plane ($x \text{ and } y \ge 0$). An object is directly above $\mathbf{A}$ between planes $z=1$ and $z=2-y$. What is the volume of the object?

My apologies for the bad english, I hope I made myself understood. I'm in a bit of a hurry and would grately appreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$V=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x^2}\!\!\!\!\int_1^{2-y}dz\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: OK, one more question. Is it "enough" to state that the limits for the integrals came from: Z: directly from question, Y: x-axis and parabel top, X: y-axis and point where the parabel intersects with x-axis. Or should this be explained more thoroughly? Again sorry for the butchered language.

Comment: I would suggest drawing a diagram for $(x,y)$.  For $z$ the only thing to be careful about is to see that in the given region $y\le1$ and so $2-y\ge1$.